Multi repo development flow in .NET vs Java/Maven
I'm used to the Java/Maven development flow where if I have two projects in two different repositories, with project A depends on project B, I can set the dependency of A to the SNAPSHOT version of B.
When I'm making changes to B, I can build and "install" with mvn install, which will build, possibly test, package and save a copy of the package in the local maven repository, which makes it immediately available to any other project, like for example project A. Then it's easy to work on both projects in parallel without the need to publish a new version of package B on a remote maven repository for later pulling into project A.
I'm now trying to apply a similar development flow with two .NET projects/solutions (A' and B') in two different repos. But I'm strugglying to determine the minimum necessary steps to make a nuget package B' available to project A'.
Is there a standard local nuget repository that can be used as source for any project on the same machine? Can I easily push nuget package B' there and pull it into project A'? How does versioning work when using Nerdbank git versioning? Can I avoid constantly updating the version of the B' dependency in project A'? What is the best way of working with two dependent .NET repositories?
